# Why does A2 say "Command is the one that betrayed you"?

Tags: nier-automata

A2 states this after finishing your first encounter with her. How did she know this info? What is she implying?

I've finished the main five endings, but I still can't figure this out. As far as I know, up to that point, she hadn't known anything about all the secrets being kept by YoRHa command; she had been just a survivor from an experiment disguised as a mission, but not aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read Anemone's logs as A2 while in the Resistance Camp? They gave A2 and Anemone's backstories, which explain A2's sentiment towards YoRHa.

> Essentially, A2 was a prototype YoRHa unit sent on a mission to Earth. Her and her squad ended up joining forces with Anemone's squad. After being attacked by machine lifeforms and having units suffer from logic virus infections, A2 was forced to mercy-kill her own companions. Later, when it came down to it, she was not sent reinforcements and was left for dead. She managed to survive, but deserted afterwards, living on with the knowledge that Command betrayed her. On top of this, having deserted YoRHa, she is now hunted by YoRHa E-type units.
>  To her, the goal of the mission was to destroy the fusion reactor. In reality, the goal was to collect combat data for future android models. I think A2 was able to put two and two together and realize that she was being used.

So, not only was A2 deserted and betrayed, she is now hunted by the organization that she was once a part of.

In terms of what she is implying-- I believe she is accused of betraying YoRHa by Command at that moment. This is her rebuttal to that. It makes sense if you take it at face value, but there is added meaning, given the fact that

> 2B is based on the original A-class unit, which is what A2 is. In some sense, 2B is simply a newer A2. Anemone even hints at the similarity when she nearly mistakes 2B for A2 upon meeting her.

I was able to find a general summary of what happened during the Pearl Harbor Descent [here](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Pearl+Harbor+Descent+Summary). This should give a general idea of what happened and why A2 (correctly) felt betrayed.

Comment: ok, i understand. I had already read that summary ingame. If not sending reinforcements is the thing that made her felt betray, i understand. That's maybe the whole point. Otherwise, A2 was not aware she was part of an experiment. She discovered it at the library, iirc. From my point of view, she was in a mission, mission was hard, didnt get reinforcements, completed mission,deserted. See why i have hard time finding a relation?

Comment: @Illiax I believe A2 realized that her survival was not intended by Command, which is why she felt betrayed. I'll add what I originally wrote here into the answer so I can put it into a spoiler block.

Comment: I think that settles it then. From there she suggest it to 2B, 9S since she figure out that there is something smellya t YoRHa. Thank you

Comment: Btw, for those who were wondering what chapter is it, I believe you can access the logs at `14_01` (Pascal's Despair) right at the beginning by talking to Anemone some more.

Answer (score 4):

It has already passed more than a month since your post, so if you may no longer want any answers, but I would like to add my comment here.

I am a native Japanese speaker and I noticed the English translation for this A2's line does not seem to be correct. On first encounter with A2, 9S asked her "Why did you betray us?" More precisely, she replied "Command is the one that betrayed **me**(or us)." So I guess A2 did not know anything about 2B or 9S's situation.

Comment: That's interesting. It might be worth mentioning that if the JP version translates to "me" **or** "us", it's possible that A2 is grouping herself along *with* 2B and 9S, which might imply that she believes Command has betrayed all of YoRHa itself.

Comment: The original Japanese A2's line is "裏切ったのは司令部だろ" which does not mention who is betrayed. If I try to translate this really literally, it would be "Command is the one that betrayed." But considering the context and the way of A2' saying, she probably means she is the one betrayed.

So that is her answer to 9S's question, "Why did you betray us?" She said she did not betray, but Command betrayed her. 

It could mean "us" instead of "me," but in that case it means her prototype group not including A2 or 9S. This is just my guess but it sounds like that to me.

Comment: @Yuricy Oh my god!!! that's so cool to know. I still knew there was something wrong! Thank you!!

Comment: @llliax No problem at all. I'm happy to hear that! :)